# How can I get a simple Web socket up and running in my Node app

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a very basic Node.js app running on my local machine, accessible at http://localhost:3000/ All working fine.

I want to add a web socket server to the app and then to make a connection to it from a local html page.

I have followed code examples from the internet but am having no luck. I never see the console.log that I expect to see on the 'connection' event.

In app.js I have the following code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
```

My existing app.listen call looks like this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var m_server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server online on http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

I use the return value of the above in the following call:

```
var m_webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer( { server: m_server, autoAcceptConnections: true} );

m_webSocketServer.on('connection', function (ws)
                        {
                            console.log("A connection");
                        }
                    );

console.log("At End");
```

That's it on the server side.

In my client web page body I have in the onload event:

```
alert("Here");
this.m_websocketConnection = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:3000');
alert(this.m_websocketConnection);
```

I had hoped to see the "A connection" message from the server side, I do not, I just see "At End" followed by "Server online on http://localhost:3000" in the console.

and in the browser I see "Here" and "[object WebSocket]"

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update: less that a minute after composing this question I found the problem!

On the client side I changed:

```
new WebSocket('wss://localhost:3000');
```

to

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000')
```

Thanks.